# What is Yamlokam? How is it different from Naraka?

Tags: yamaloka, naraka

Before this [suggested edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1327) was rejected I had the impression that Yamalokam is Naraka(the hell). And I was told [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16267595#16267595) that Yamlokam is not the hell. So I am really curious. What is Yamlokam? How is it different from Naraka?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yamaloka generally means the province of Yama. It's not actually same as Naraka (hell), but generally said so. After a person dies then he is taken to Yamaloka. Yama as the judge from Chitragupta's account determines the person's sins and virtues. Then as per that he sends the person either to hell or heaven.

So as per my experience from the scriptures I would put it thus:  **Yama-loka is just like a court house where people are temporarily held until their judgement is over and Narak (hell) is like a prison where a person goes to experience his punishment**.

> By the order of Yama, his minions (*yama duta*) put the sinful souls
>   into hell. But they take a virtuous person who observed the laws of
>   the *rishis* (Vashistha etc.) to heaven. [Agni Puran - 203.5]