# Who was the god of death before yama?

Tags: yuga, yama, naraka, yamaloka

Yama is a post created for specific jeevatamans to take charge of Judgement of Jeevatmas and their karma in Bhuloka/Mrityuloka. Before Yama or Dharmaraja who was the king of [Yamaloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/461/what-is-yamlokam-how-is-it-different-from-naraka) ? Also, in which Manvantara and Maha Yuga he was appointed as the God of death?

Comment: [Yamaloka is diffrent from Narkaloka](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/461/what-is-yamlokam-how-is-it-different-from-naraka) and i think he is king of Yamloka not narka but i can be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How was Yama born and how he became the king of Yamaloka?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-was-yama-born-and-how-he-became-the-king-of-yamaloka)

Comment: Sir i knw he was the sister of yamuna...my question concerns other part too...that is...even before him ppl died...so who took care of taking away their souls

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi In the Vedas, Yama is said to have been the first mortal who died. By virtue of precedence, he became the ruler of the departed [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yama#cite_note-8)

Comment: Then what about manu sir? even he was the first mortal

Comment: **first mortal who died.** but i am searching for a good source for this statement first.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi you can reword your answer and remove who appointed him part as its already answered in link question and make it distinct then that question to save from closing.

Comment: (Here)[blog.onlineprasad.com/who-was-the-first-man-according-to-hindu-mythology/]link it tells manu waa the first mortal

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi i don't know how its difficult to understand difference between **first mortal who died** and **first mortal** and manu didn't died first, so many mortal died before him.

Comment: @AnkitSharma the first mortal is manu...i suppose isnt it?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi but he isn't the first mortal to die..

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Manu was the first born mortal but he was not the first mortal to die. I can't write it in more easy words.  Better come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) so that i can explain you in depth.

Comment: And yes sir here someone said naraklok and yamalok are different...can someone explain me?